# Android Studio Gradle Error on Fresh Project (OS X)

Tags: java, android, macos

I recently installed Android Studio on my Mac, as I planned on traveling this week, but I'm getting a very strange error when compiling even freshly made projects. I made sure jdk was up to date, and that all the right packages from the SDK Manager were downloaded, so I'm stumpted. This is the error I get every time:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'LoLNexus'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2.
     Required by:
         :LoLNexus:unspecified
      > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

Comment: post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle

*File* -> *Settings* -> Gradle -> if using deault try to download 1.12 gradle version and set path for it

I got same projet on OS X just update

Comment: I have the same problem .. do you have a solution to that?

Answer (score -1):

Update your  build.gradle by changing gradle version there to 0.9.+.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
```